# How to edit colours in an area with Lightroom's Color Mixer?

Tags: lightroom, photo-editing

I have a picture where I'd like to emphasize the blue sky without messing up the colour of the clouds.
To do this I thought I'd use the Color Mixer in Lightroom, which gives me the effect I want.
Unfortunately, the colour is also present in other areas of the photo, where I don't want the changes to be.

What would be the way to edit **only** the blue colour and saturation of the sky (preferably using the Color Mixer), without affecting the colour of the stairs and buildings?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can’t use the color mixer with a local adjustment brush in Lightroom.
What you can do is to brush the area which covers the sky only and then you can make adjustments to color temperature, saturation or vibrance for the brushed area, without affecting the unbrushed areas.
By using a cooler color temperature, the blue color should be more blue, and if you then add a bit of saturation or vibrancy, it should be possible.

Even better would be to use photoshop, add an extra layer where you make the color adjustments and then mask that on top of the background layer.